# error: flexible array member in a struct with no named members

Tags: c, struct

```
struct array
{
    char concan[];
};
```

above code is the only part that refuses to compile

unless I do this the code does not work:

```
struct array
{
    int x;//some random useless variable
    char concan[];
};
```

If I do not put the random useless variable, I get the error which is in title.

Why does the error happen?

Also the code works as intended when I put the useless variable.

Comment: It is not allowed because `sizeof(struct array)` would be need to be`0` and C standard is allergic to zero-sized objects.

Comment: What would be a the use of such a structure which you won't be able to achieve using a simple pointer?

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the error happen?

The idea behind "flexible array members" is to extend the size of a struct at allocation time by a variable amount of bytes (`>= 0`). Instead of doing a separate allocation for the variable-length data, it can be done in one step when allocating the enclosing struct.

A struct with only such a member would be unusable by itself and pointless. The compiler cannot instantiate it because its size would be zero, and if you needed it just for the variable-length array, you would be better off with an ordinary variable-length allocation.

Answer (score 1):

C99 standard, which introduced flexible array members, requires that at least one other named member exist in the structure when a flexible array member is used.

"A flexible array member is permitted as the last element of a structure even though it has incomplete type, provided that the structure has more than one named member."

From: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=declarations-flexible-array-members